# How to change Checkbox image style in Material UI. React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to change my little black icon in checkbox to another color!

This is my code.

Material ui theme:

```
export const colors: IAppColors = {
   darkTheme: {
      primary: {
         placeholder: "#607589",
         bright: "#37AFE2",
         light: "#276899",
         grey: "#242F3D",
         main: "#17212B",
         dark: "#0E1621",
      },

      secondary: {
         grey: "rgba(255,255,255, .08)",
         light: "rgba(255,255,255, .1)",
         main: "#fff",
         dark: "",
      },
   },
};
```

Mui theme checkbox styles:

```
      MuiCheckbox: {
         styleOverrides: {
            root: {
               transition: "all .2s ease",

               "&.Mui-checked": {
                  ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                     color: colors.darkTheme.primary.bright,
                  },
               },

               ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                  fontSize: "2.2rem",
               },

               ".MuiTouchRipple-root": {
                  opacity: "0.3",
               },
            },
         },
      },
```

[Checkbox itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAPQz.png)

So, how do i change this little black icon color to white

This little icon color inherits from my mui theme palette main color.

I tried to change my main color in my theme color palette to white, and it worked for me, but, i have a black theme, so i need to change only this little icon color, not an app main color.

Comment: You should try some online checkbox generators

Answer (score 0):

you can change Icon and checkedIcon prop in the Checkbox component

```
<Checkbox
          color="primary"
          icon={props.disabled ? <CheckboxDisabledIcon /> : <CheckboxIcon />}
          checkedIcon={indeterminate ? <CheckboxIndeterminateIcon /> : <CheckboxActiveIcon />}
        />
```

like this